# Are creational design patterns useless in Dependency Injection environment ( like SpringBoot)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, oop, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I am studying design patterns, and at one moment caught myself with an idea, that most creational patterns like Factory and Abstract Factory are not so useful in the scope of a dependency injection environment where we usually don't create objects with the `new` keyword but "inject" them from some context. I also understand that most probably I am wrong and I need a good explanation to make things clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not wrong. There are five creational patterns in the GoF book and you will likely never use any of them as a Java developer.

1. **Abstract Factory** - Dependency Injection certainly reduces, if not eliminates, the need for this pattern. It is well established that [Service Locator is an Anti-Pattern](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) and if you take a step further to ask [Is the Service Locator pattern any different from the Abstract Factory pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5698026/1371329) the answer is, *not really*.
2. **Builder** is a pattern you *are* likely to use in Java, *but not the version in the GoF book*. As a Java developer, you will most likely implement Josh Bloch's version from Effective Java (or have Lombok implement it for you). See: [How to implement the Builder Design Pattern in the right way?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66524505/1371329)
3. **Factory Method** is simply the creational version of the Template Method pattern. While this can still be a useful pattern, it is fundamentally based on inheritance; and we all know by now to [prefer composition over inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49002/1371329).
4. **Prototype** is a pattern that is highly language specific. In other languages it is critical. In Java, not so much. [Prototype pattern is not a useful performance tool in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58252134/1371329) and the Prototype bean lifestyle implemented by Spring is [not equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26609980/1371329) to the GoF pattern.
5. **Singleton** is [divisive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12755539/1371329), even amongst the GoF themselves. It is widely considered an anti-pattern today. You are far more likely to utilize the Singleton bean lifestyle implemented by Spring, which (again) is [not equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2637864/1371329) to the GoF pattern.

Comment: I'm really at odds here whether to up-vote.  Service locator is completely different than abstract factory. Abstract Factory mainly deals with building related families of objects, and is extremely useful in conjunction with Builder ( The GOF one, not Bloch's builder ) Service locator deals with dependency lookup, where as Abstract Factory will usually be used in the opposite style, with DI.  Factory method's inheritance counter part is "simple factory" or "regular class factory", the 1 product version of Abstract Factory.

Comment: Service Locator and Abstract Factory are two mechanisms of achieving [Dependency Inversion _without_ Inversion of Control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65588618/1371329). They are both undesirable from the perspective that IoC is ideal and neither of them achieves it.

Comment: @jaco0646 thank you for clarify this moment for me , as I see you mention patterns that are not so useful in DI environment , can you also provide a list of useful one ?

Comment: @MisaD. if you want to do OOP, you should have a strong grasp of patterns that utilize composition. For example, Decorator and Adapter are simple, ubiquitous patterns in OOP. From the category of behavioral patterns, Observer is a very powerful yet underutilized design.

Answer (score 1):

Using a **Dependency Injection** / **Inversion of Control** framework such as Spring does indeed reduce the need for The Gang of Four Creational Patterns, but may not eliminate them.

First, let's notice that Spring supports a scope ( instance creation mode ) called "**Singleton**". And while its implementation varies from the GOF suggested one, many of the ideas are the same. In this case, if Spring is prevalent throughout your project, you would not need the GOF singleton. As noted elsewhere, developers should be wary of Singleton abuse, as Singletons can lead to static, untestable and unconfigurable code.

Next, the **Abstract Factory** is used to create entire families of related products. The 1 product simplified type was not even mentioned in the GOF book. I suppose they considered it to be too well known already. In a Spring environment you will often use Spring to inject the product you need instead of creating it through a factory, but in some instances, you will inject the factory instead, and then create products from it!

**Prototype** is another confusing one. The GOF patterns is rarely used in languages with reflection as they really do have other ways, although not necessarily better ways for creating a copy of an object. The confusing bit is that Spring uses the word "Prototype" to denote a Bean which is not a singleton, I guess because they originally assumed that all new instances of this Bean would essentially start out the same.

**Factory Method** is usually used by in Frameworks, and less so in Application level code. It lets the user of the Framework decide what kind of object is created when the framework chooses to create an object. Spring actually does something very similar but without inheritance. When you mark a function as @Bean, Spring calls your function when it wants to create a new instance, replacing Factory Method's inheritance mechanism with Spring's reflection and interception.

Comment: In what instance would you inject an Abstract Factory instead of its products?

Comment: One example could be when you need more than one instance. A common practice is to inject EntityManagerFactory so you can create an EntityManager for a particular persistence unit.

Answer (score 0):

DI frameworks like Spring initialize and manage beans. Creational pattern can be used to create domain (bussines) objects.